# Why am I experiencing random bluetooth disconnects?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, keynote

I have an iPad Air 2 64GB now running iOS 8.3. I've experienced problems where when using Keynote on my iPhone 5S to remote control a keynote presentation on my iPad, the connection will be dropped at random times during the presentation. I attributed this to Keynote bugs, but then my iPad also started randomly losing connections to my Logitech Ultrathin keyboard cover (the onscreen keyboard would appear) or I'd type a certain character and it would start repeating ad infinitum. I removed the interference factor from the equation by noticing that the problem would also occur within my office with thick walls and no bluetooth devices nearby … so I had Logitech replace the keyboard, but the connection drops still occur. I also reset all settings on my iPad, which didn't help.

So my next question is this: could the bluetooth hardware on my iPad Air 2 be flakey? Everything else about it works fine.

Comment: how flaky is it, how far can you go before loosing the connection?

Comment: It happens about every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: By the way, the Logitech Ultrathin keyboard cover for iPad Air 2 definitely has a defective bluetooth implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a whim, after upgrading to iOS 9, I tried the same Logitech keyboard with my iPad Air 2; the problems no longer exist! It looks like Apple indeed fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not alone and no fix in sight at the moment according to this report.

[How to potentially fix iPad Bluetooth Problems](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/10/20/ipad-problems-fixes/)

> iOS 8 Bluetooth problems are among the most common iOS issues and they
> were a big problem inside iOS 8. We ourselves have run into iOS 8
> Bluetooth issues with the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus and while iOS 8.1
> delivers fixes for Bluetooth issues, we expect Bluetooth problems to
> persist inside Apple’s brand new iOS 8 update.
>
> There doesn’t appear to be a cure all, we’ve heard about a few
> possible fixes that iPad users will want to try. iOS users have
> singled out “Reset All Settings” as a solid fix. It hasn’t worked for
> everyone but there are a ton of people that are claiming success after
> trying it on their iPhone. It should work for Apple’s iPad as well.
>
> To do this, open up the iPad and head to Settings > General > Reset >
> Reset All Settings. This is going to take a bit of time and users will
> lose all saved settings but the pay off is that it seems to be fixing
> Bluetooth issues for many people. It’s certainly worth a try if
> Bluetooth keeps acting up after Apple’s iOS 8.1 upgrade.

For the time been, you can file your report with Apple and hope for the best.

https://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html

Comment: See my comments above: I have already tried "Reset All Settings." Note that the problem has not improved with iOS 8.3!!

Comment: correct, that is what the reports says. it only worked for some not for the majority and Apple has not succeeded in fixing it so far. You question was is the Bluetooth Flaky--Yes it is.

Comment: OK, so this is not a hardware failure? It's pretty incredible that such major problems persist in a .3 release.

Comment: I am with you on this one :) sorry I could not fix your problem, but it is in Apple hands to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my iPad Air 2 and Logitech Ultrathin keyboard for months! A while back, I connected my Apple wireless keyboard to my iPad. I never removed it after I was done using it. So I just now removed it by selecting “forget this device“. Now my Logitech keyboard works! OMG, I was going nuts!

Answer (score -2):

its not hardware. I degraded to 8.3 and now it is consistently dropping Bluetooth to both my car and headset. That never happened before. Thanks Apple. Let's. Yosemite degrade was locking system for a couple minutes after it was sleeping.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please consider editing your answer for clarity. As it stands it's very difficult to understand how it can help the OP.